# how to create a random loss sample in r using if function

Tags: r, if-statement, distribution, data-generation, beta-distribution

I am working currently on generating some random data for a school project.

I have created a variable in R using a binomial distribution to determine if an observation had a loss yes=1 or not=0.
Afterwards I am trying to generate the loss amount using a random distribution for all observations which already had a loss (=1).

As my loss amount is a percentage it can be anywhere between 0

[What Is The Intuition Behind Beta Distribution  @  stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47771/what-is-the-intuition-behind-beta-distribution)

In a third step I am looking for an if statement, which combines my two variables.

Please find below my code (which is only working for the Loss_Y_N variable):

```
Loss_Y_N = rbinom(1000000,1,0.01)
Loss_Amount = dbeta(x, 10, 990, ncp = 0, log = FALSE)
```

ideally I can combine the two into something like

```
if(Loss_Y_N=1 then Loss_Amount=dbeta(...) #... is meant to be a random variable with mean=0.15 and should be 0<x=<1
else Loss_Amount=0)
```

Any input highly appreciated!

Comment: So, to clarify, you need to generate a random number between 0 and 1 with mean a specific mean? You could probably edit your question to specify that as the problem and avoid all the extra fluff

Comment: Loss_Amount = dbeta(...) * Loss_Y_N . Wherever, Loss_Y_N is 0, Loss amount will be 0.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. Much appreciated. Can you please explain to me what I should put in the parenthesis to have a loss distribution around 15% but allow it to be between 0<x=<100? Best regards, Alex

Comment: @Ben Knoble yes maybe you are right. Actually I only need to find out how to best simulate a loss distribution between 0 and 100% with a mean of 15%.

Comment: I edited your comment in Alex, but it has to reviewed as I am still low-ish rep. Hopefully it clarifies the problem for others

Comment: thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a vector for your loss proportion. Fill up the elements corresponding to losses with draws from the beta. Tweak the parameters for the beta until you get the desired result.

```
N <- 100000
loss_indicator <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.1)
loss_prop <- numeric(N)
loss_prop[loss_indicator > 0] <- rbeta(sum(loss_indicator), 10, 990)
```

Comment: thank you for your comment - much appreciated. 
What I don't  understand is that when I follow your code I don't get any observations which have a total loss (meaning that my loss_prop variable should be around 1? Am I interpreting the results wrong?

Comment: @Alex_T_86 oops, left out  the `> 0`. Try it now.

Comment: thank you! Now I just have to play around with the parameter - thank you!